# How to add a filter in PowerShell and Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to automate a report that I have to do every month and am trying to use PowerShell and Excel to do this.

Below is the code that I just came up with to open the CSV file. I need help applying a filter to A1:to G1:. So then I will be able to filter out what I need from there.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("U:\Local Group Members.csv")
$excel.visible=$true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
Import-CSV "U:\Local Group Members.csv" | Sort-Object Netbios_name0, Name0
```

How do I create the filter, and then use the filter to sort the Netbios column?

Here is the picture of the first row of the Excel column:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend performing all the sorting and filtering in PowerShell rather than Excel and then just use Export-Csv at the end to create the data file you want.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart So What you are saying is for me to not even start out with the code that I have? I am a novice at powershell and I am trying to learn how I can use powershell to automate this process. Thanks

Comment: Exactly - don't use Excel but instead do your querying and sorting in PowerShell, then Export-Csv at the end to get the report.

Answer (score 0):

What Bill is saying is leave Excel out of the equation -- the Excel COM object is incredibly painful relative to working with normal PowerShell.  As long as this is your actual question:

> How do I create the filter, and then use the filter to sort the
>   Netbios column?

Then you literally just need a single line of PowerShell to do what you want:

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | Sort-Object -Property Netbios_name0 | Export-Csv -notypeinformation newcsv.csv
```

Comment: I wanted to be able filter the Netbios column, and keep only the rows of data for the Administrators.

Comment: what column do you have data to identify "administrators" in and how can you identify them as "administrators"?